# Preventing comboBox keyboard selection

Tags: c#, combobox

As you now the user can select an item from the comboBox by keyboard directly. By mouse I block the user to select some items depending on the behind object state. What's the best solution to stop this when the user uses the keyboard?

Comment: A better, more common practice is to put in the combo box only the items that can be selected. It won't prevent keyboard usage (I, as a user, would find this offensive!) and simplify code.

Comment: agree with you. But my customer has the power in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside the usability issues arising from this sort of requirement (many users are in the habit of using the keyboard and would find it non-intuitive), you could simply handle the `KeyDown` event and set `KeyEventArgs.Cancel` to True.

```
private void myCombo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   // Cancel the event if Up or Down keys are pressed.
   if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up))
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Clarification before I get downvoted again - This is an *example* which illustrates the method. It is upto the OP to decide what keys he/she wants to disallow. ^ ^

Comment: If you have an item with text, say "xyz", on pressing 'x' it will be selected. The above code will not handle that.

Comment: My example is illustrative. I leave the exclusion of certain keyboard events to the OP.

Comment: I agree Cerebrus. I saw the method, I decided how to handle it in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

With this you can cancel all keyboard actions on your ComboBox.

Assumptions: WinForms

Comment: By that same logic, I contend that your example is too wide in scope. Notice that the OP says "I block the user to select **some items**"

Comment: My pardon for the comment then :)